# I am trying to pass data from one View Controller to another in Swift via 'prepare for segue' but it crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Good evening,

I am trying to pass data from one View Controller to another, but it crashes my program in the final View Controller. Can anyone help me?

This is the ViewController:

```
func updateAfterPlayAgain(){
    labelSay.text = ">Result<"

    scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"

    score = 0

    seconds = 10

    mainButton.isEnabled = true

    userResult.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

This is the PopUpViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var fate: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    fate.updateAfterPlayAgain()
}
```

It is from this one that I am trying to access the data from ViewController when it(PopUpViewController) closes. I would like to update the information in the ViewController when I close the PopUpViewController.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't clearly understand a couple of things - (1) What is the name of your *destination* VC class? "ViewController"? (2) Which VC does *updateAfterPlayAgain()* reside? In this destination VC? (3) If so, you aren't coding things correctly. *prepare(segue:)* is meant to pass parameters into the destination VC, not call a function in it.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Which line does it crash at? Also, please add the crash exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `prepareForSegue` is called the destination view controllers' views haven't been loaded, so all of it's outlets will be nil.

Outlets are set up as implicitly unwrapped optionals, and that causes a crash if you try to reference an outlet that's nil. That's why you're crashing.

You should not call `updateAfterPlayAgain()` from prepareForSegue, since it tries to reference your outlets before they are connected. Instead call `updateAfterPlayAgain()` from `viewWillAppear` (or better yet from `viewDidLoad`, since that only gets called once when a view controller's views are first loaded.)

Comment: My pleasure. If I've answered your question you should accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Banjo, your question is not completely clear. Please add the crash it self so we will have more information ti help you.

From what I see, when you create a screen, the @IBOutlet labels, are still nil until the screen performs the "viewDidLoad" method, therefore, instead of updating the screen in the prepare(for segue), I'd set a flag using a boolean, i.e.: "requiresUpdate: Bool", and set it here, then in the viewDidAppear, check the flag and call updateAferPlayAgain.

If you are talking about dismissing a controller and updating the main controller instead, you should read about how to use "unwind segues" and handling their events, this way the parent controller gets the event of the displayed controller closing.

This article should help you with that:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/

Good luck.